# How to fill vertical space with Vuetify

Tags: css, vuetifyjs3

If I have a container with two rows, how can I make the first row fill the height, so that the second row is at the bottom of the screen and only takes the required space?

[image]

Here is my current code.

```
<template>
  <v-container class="d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap">
    <v-row class="flex-grow-1"> Content </v-row>
    <v-row> Button </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Vue or this library, but I googled for the docs and this page seems to explain [all the Flexbox related classes you can use.](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/)

It seems that adding the class `flex-1-1-100` will set `flex: 1 1 100% !important` in CSS, which is what you want on the first item to take up all the space, and then don't set anything on the second item to make it only takes up the space it needs to.

```html
<template>
  <v-container
    class="d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap">
    <v-row class="flex-1-1-100"> Content </v-row>
    <v-row> Button </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Here's [a demo of it working on their playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkt9uwiAUxl+FcC1F1+2m6YzbHsN60T9HZQNKgFaN8d13oM509WImSxMC53C+3zlfWZ/pmzFJ3wHNaO5BGVl6WBaakLxndat9KTTYcCaklqVzrwVt2FbCkYQFr8hO6WGv24MtDal2zELDpNjtPWiWFnQod/4kAcv3EDIZSedzcxySERiRtj3cOKpkC2LCEuUX4ZvPg77prJFwQ7wUdEk+sFnQnuQ8qvwliSqV7CYa7533rf4lEfY3HzCS85FLdEaFMq31TJUm+XStRhvPoay4JlxBMxIjIYY+hzN64L1xGed1o7GsASl6m2jwXBvFV3iN2057oYA1rVqlSZo880Y4Pw4n4BSrsE8HFkUKOhthvNieHkBdb0bC4mlAXGNMlpULjDttjsAeLP5l3YDF1/HgSJOy8ViT1N1ogX4p9AUNl0J/uYnXtYs+r3+a/N/MUS1IbQLxMqOxUUQPFXTzDYpPEf4=) where I added some extra classes for padding and background colors, and a container height so that it is possible to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it out and it works because of the explicit height setting (in your playground example). My question was too imprecise. I'd like the first row to fill up the remaining space of the viewport without explicitly setting the height of the container, so that the second row is at the bottom.

Comment: I found this part of the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/sizing/ - There is a utility class `h-screen` which will let the container fill the screen.

Comment: Yes, the height has to be set to something or else there is no "remaining height" left to fill up.  Without a height set the elements only take up the space needed